# Fetching mongo DB object using Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to query mongodb object and based on the Id i.e. 456 present in responseBody.

[image]

Below is the Java code I have written

```
String Id = "456";

Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("responseBody.Id").is(Id));
dataList = mongoTemplate.find(query, Data.class);
```

the above code is working perfectly fine. But because of the change in requirements I need to store the JSON in the responseBody as shown below.

[image]

My query is how do I fetch the entire mongoDB object by querying the Id that I have and the object being present in responseBody -> body.

Comment: No, that is NOT "Spring Data JPA". It is nothing at all to do with the JPA API either. It is "Spring Data MongoDB". Please understand what API you are actually using

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use JPARespository classes and use the methods like findById or findByName as follows:

```
@Transactional
@Repository
public interface InstituteRepository extends MongoRepository<Institute, String> {

    Institute findByInstituteId(long id);

}
```

Comment: Correction : this is NOT a "JPARepository". There is no JPA API involvement here. It is MongoDB. MongoRepository is nothing to do with JPARepository